# export PATH creating a redundant path

Tags: perl, bash, terminal, environment-variables

I need to add some perl scripts to PATH, but when I do, and try to run the scripts, it can't find the files. For some reason it is using a redundant path and doesn't find it. I dont know how to describe the problem but the code is pretty self-explanatory.

```
[lsk250@murphy portfolio-handout]$ pwd
/home/lsk250/portfolio-handout
[lsk250@murphy portfolio-handout]$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/lsk250/portfolio-handout/ 
[lsk250@murphy portfolio-handout]$ time_series_symbol_project.pl 
env: /home/lsk250/portfolio-handout//home/lsk250/portfolio-handout/get_data.pl: No such file or directory
sh: line 1: 17758 Aborted                 (core dumped) time_series_project _data.in 8 AWAIT 300 ARIMA 2 1 2 2> /dev/null
```

Any ideas whats the right `export` command I should use to get this right?

Comment: You don't need a trailing slash, though I wouldn't it expect that to be a fatal mistake.

Comment: What does you shebang link look like? Does it have the wrong line ending perhaps (`\r\n` instead of `\n`)?

Comment: try running it in a fresh terminal session as you may have done a `PATH=$PWD:PATH` from the command line that you have forgotten about. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in how you export PATH variable except that you may already have your "pwd" there.

As far as I can see the get_data.pl is called from time_series_symbol_project.pl (or from some other script called from time_series_symbol_project.pl and so on) and I would check how it is called.

Perhaps you could also see if PATH is changed somewhere in your scripts.

Comment: PATH is not changed from the scripts.

Comment: Could you show how are you calling one perl script from another?

Comment: via the system perl command: `system "get_data.pl | other.pl"`

Comment: Which shell, version, platform?

Comment: tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,color,filec

Comment: Interesting, I don't get this behavior with tcsh [tcsh 6.17.02 (Astron) 2010-05-12 (i586-intel-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,nd,color,filec] here on Debian GNU/Linux 6.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing the "shebang" line (`#!`) and/or file permissions on 'get_data.pl' is incorrect.